# How to set other first screen when I am logged in

Tags: react-native

How can I choose according value in AsyncStorage which screen should be displayed? I don't know why setting screen value 'Home' to InitialScreen variable doesn't work?

Once I log in **login.js** screen and I close app, after launching the app again I am navigated to **login.js**. But now I want to go to **home.js** screen.

Parent's file **routes.js**:

```
let InitialScreen
const RoutesNavigation = StackNavigator({
    Login: { screen: Login },
    Home: { screen: Home }
}, {
        initialRouteName: InitialScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: false,
        }
    });


export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        value = AsyncStorage.getItem('name');
        if (value !== null) {
            InitialScreen = 'Home'; //This doesn't change Initial screen!!!
            console.log("JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ routes.js value !== null ");
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <RoutesNavigation />
        );
    }
}
```

This is **login.js**, where I store value from received json:

```
export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
        }
    }    

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput} placeholder='Username'
                    onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                />

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput} placeholder='Password'
                    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                />

                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.btn}
                    onPress={this.login}>
                    <Text>Log in</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        );
    }

    login = () => {

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('userName', this.state.username);
        formData.append('password', this.state.password);

        fetch('http://....', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })            
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log("JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ name: " + responseJson.name);
                AsyncStorage.setItem('name', responseJson.name);
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
            })
            .catch(()  => {
                console.log("JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ Wrong connection");
                alert('Wrong connection');
            })
    }
}
```

This is **home.js**:

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <Text style={styles.text}> Member area. You are logged in. </Text>

                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.btn}
                    onPress={this.logout}>
                    <Text>Log out</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        );
    }

    logout = () => {

        AsyncStorage.removeItem('name');
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
        console.log("JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ Logged out");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your navigator in here:

```
value = AsyncStorage.getItem('name');
if (value !== null) {
  InitialScreen = 'Home';

  const RoutesNavigation = StackNavigator({
      Login: { screen: Login },
      Home: { screen: Home }
    },{
      initialRouteName: InitialScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
      header: false,
    }
  });
}
```

Because you are creating your navigator at the top with empty initial route but you are changing value in here so you must create here. 
Hope it will work.

Comment: Now I get Error: RoutesNavigation is not defined

Comment: declare a global RoutesNavigation.

Comment: Yes, I did it. But now I am always navigated to 'Home' screen. Also when I am logged out.

Comment: According to your application change routes. For example create a default route. If is there anything in asyncStorage change your routes and use it. and in else block just return that default route. And dont forget asyncStorage is async you should use callback as @Muhammed Mirza said

Answer (score 0):

AsyncStorage is async.Because of the js nature thread won't wait result of this

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('name');
```

use callback with getItem

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('name',(error,result) => {
if (result!== null) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but result is always null, because I never jump into that if.